# What is the meaning of wildcard in .NET Core Version?

Tags: .net-core

in `package.json`

there is a `version` property, in my empty project it's set to `1.0.0-*`,

what is the meaning of the wildcard? Does it somehow evaluate to specific number or does it simply mean *all*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The star create a floating version. So in your example the package must be version `1.0.0-` but after that it will get the highest version of the package available.

So if you had 6.0.* it would grab the latest version of 6.0.x